# HDD health - what do the numbers actually mean?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Defraggler had a little tool that shows the health of the HDD.

[image]

But I'm unsure what this all means. Could someone explain them, and which values are good and which are bad?

Comment: While you see the numbers, means the HDD is good. Once you stop seeing them, means its dead :)

Comment: Might as well copy and paste the SMART wiki page.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Is this SMART? Didn't know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a wiki here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes

You will have to judge the values accordingly, relative to the HDD's specs.